# how to get the 3rd value of req.body?

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have a dynamic form which is outputting inputs with the name+1 .and I want to get the data from my form to MySQL

I tried to add a loop which increments the field name by 1 
i tried to req.body.itemID+1

```
app.post("/admin/add_challan_db", ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var sql =
    "INSERT INTO `invoice`VALUES (DEFAULT,?,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,1,DEFAULT)";
  var sql2 =
    "INSERT INTO `invoice_details`(`id`, `invoice_id`, `item_id`, `qty`, `current_rate`, `total`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?)";

  con.query(sql, [req.body.customerid], function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // console.log(result);
    console.log("Employee Id:- " + result.insertId);
    for (var i = 1; i <= req.body.totalform; i++) {
      con.query(
        sql2,
        [
          req.body.insertId,
          req.body.itemid + i,
          req.body.itemqty + i,
          req.body.itemprice + i,
          (req.body.qty + i) * (req.body.rate + i)
        ],
        function(err, result, fields) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }
    // var k = 1;

    /// console.log(req.body[2]);
    res.send(req.body);
  });
});
```

Here is an example of how the `req.body` looks like:

```
{
    "totalform": "2",
    "customerid": "1",
    "itemid1": "2",
    "itemqty1": "3",
    "itemtotal1": "1500",
    "itemprice1": "5",
    "itemid2": "1",
    "itemqty2": "3",
    "itemtotal2": "1500",
    "itemprice2": "5000"
}
```

Comment: Can you add a snippet of how the `req.body` object looks like?

Comment: {"totalform":"2","customerid":"1","itemid1":"2","itemqty1":"3","itemtotal1":"1500","itemprice1":"5","itemid2":"1","itemqty2":"3","itemtotal2":"1500","itemprice2":"5000"}

Comment: i slove it by doing this

Comment: for(var i = 1 ;i<= req.body.totalform ; i++)
    {
     var itemid = 'itemid'+i;
     var itemqty = 'itemqty'+i;
     var itemprice = 'itemprice'+i;
     var itemtotal = 'itemtotal'+i;
     con.query(sql2, [result.insertId,req.body[itemid],req.body[itemqty],req.body[itemprice],(req.body[itemqty])*(req.body[itemprice])], function (err, result, fields) {
       if (err) console.log(err);

      });
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`Bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics#Bracket_notation) when you want to access the keys of an object dynamically. For example, if you wanted to get the key `item1` you could do it this way: `req.body["item" + "1"]`. Whatever is inside the brackets will evaluate first, and the result will be used as the key.

On your example, it would look something like this:

```
app.post("/admin/add_challan_db", ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  var sql =
    "INSERT INTO `invoice`VALUES (DEFAULT,?,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,1,DEFAULT)";
  var sql2 =
    "INSERT INTO `invoice_details`(`id`, `invoice_id`, `item_id`, `qty`, `current_rate`, `total`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?)";

  con.query(sql, [req.body.customerid], function(err, result, fields) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // console.log(result);
    console.log("Employee Id:- " + result.insertId);
    for (var i = 1; i <= req.body.totalform; i++) {
      var itemid = req.body["itemid" + i];
      var itemqty = req.body["itemqty" + i];
      var itemtotal = req.body["itemtotal" + i];
      var itemprice = req.body["itemprice" + i];
      var qty = req.body["qty" + i];
      var rate = req.body["rate" + i];
      con.query(
        sql2,
        [insertId, itemId, itemQty, itemPrice, qty * rate],
        function(err, result, fields) {
          if (err) console.log(err);
        }
      );
    }
    // var k = 1;

    /// console.log(req.body[2]);
    res.send(req.body);
  });
});
```

I tried to keep as much of your code as possible while making it more readable. Bear in mind that some of the keys you used on your system, are not included in the example `req.body` you provided. If these values can be undefined, you should add the proper guards to avoid errors.

All this said, let me add an additional opinion, even though your method works, when you have a variable list of objects, one usually uses an `array` in JavaScript. It would simplify your code a lot, and it would make it far more readable.

Comment: ok that is good . i am pretty new to JavaScript frameworks .i will try your example

Answer (score -1):

```
  for(var i = 1 ;i<= req.body.totalform ; i++)
    {
     var itemid = 'itemid'+i;
     var itemqty = 'itemqty'+i;
     var itemprice = 'itemprice'+i;
     var itemtotal = 'itemtotal'+i;
     con.query(sql2, [result.insertId,req.body[itemid],req.body[itemqty],req.body[itemprice],(req.body[itemqty])*(req.body[itemprice])], function (err, result, fields) {
       if (err) console.log(err);

      });
    }
```